# GWT SerializationException__Ljava_lang_String_2V while doing RPC

Tags: java, gwt

Below are my service, serviceImpl and async callback interfaces. Appreciate if someone can help me understand **why the submitTeam(...) isn't being called** (I howeve see that isValidEmail(...) is being invoked when used). At least provide me the approach for debugging this as currently I am unable to use eclipse debugger (eclipse is not stopping at breakpoints) and the sysout/syserr statements are not being logged to the console either :-(.

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("registrationService")
public interface RegistrationService extends RemoteService
{
    Boolean isValidEmail(String email);

    String submitTeam(String teamName, List<Player> players);
}

public interface RegistrationServiceAsync
{
    void isValidEmail(String email, AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback);

    void submitTeam(String teamName, List<Player> players, AsyncCallback<String> callback);
}

public class SubmitTeamCallback implements AsyncCallback<String> {
    private final Label status;

    public SubmitTeamCallback(Label s) {
        status = s;
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        status.setText(caught.getMessage());
    }

    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        System.out.println("" + getClass().getName() + " : " + result);
        status.setText(result);
    }
}


public class RegistrationCallback implements AsyncCallback<Boolean>
{
    private final Label         status;
    private final PlayerWidget  playerWidget;
    private Boolean             isValidSharedFlag;

    public RegistrationCallback(Label s, PlayerWidget pw, Boolean isValid)
    {
        status = s;
        playerWidget = pw;
        setIsValidSharedFlag(isValid);
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
        status.setText(caught.getMessage());
    }

    public void onSuccess(Boolean result)
    {
        if (result.equals(Boolean.FALSE))
        {
            playerWidget.invalidEmail();
            String oldText = status.getText();

            status.setText(oldText + "Please specify a valid email address for the captain.");
            setIsValidSharedFlag(Boolean.FALSE);
        } else
        {
            playerWidget.validEmail();
            String newText = status.getText().replace("Please specify a valid email address for the captain.", "");
            status.setText(newText);
            setIsValidSharedFlag(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    public void setIsValidSharedFlag(Boolean isValidSharedFlag)
    {
        this.isValidSharedFlag = isValidSharedFlag;
    }

    public Boolean getIsValidSharedFlag()
    {
        return isValidSharedFlag;
    }
}

public class RegistrationServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        RegistrationService {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
    private final Emailer emailer = new Emailer();
    private final EmailValidator validator = new EmailValidator();

    public Boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return validator.validate(email);
    }

    public String submitTeam(String teamName, List<Player> players) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "This is a test log");

        System.out.println("This is a test log");
        boolean emailSent = false;
        for (Player p : players) {
            System.out.println("Emailing to captain");
            if (p instanceof Captain) {
                if (!validator.validate(p.getEmail())) {
                    return "Please specify a valid email";
                }
                System.out.println("Emailing to captain");
                emailSent = emailer.email(p);
            }
        }
        if (emailSent) {
            System.out.println("Email sent successfully");
            return teamName
                    + " has been successfully registered. Please pay the registration fee to confirm registration. Thank you.";
        } else {
            return "Unable to send email. Please email the team details [Team name, minimum of 6 players, captain's email address and phone number] to funpluscharity@gmail.com";
        }
    }
}
```

**Below method is going to invoke the RPC calls**

```
private void registerTeam() {
            System.out.println("Received request to dubmit team");
            StringBuilder statusText = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Boolean isValid = true;

                RegistrationServiceAsync service = (RegistrationServiceAsync) GWT
                        .create(RegistrationService.class);
                ServiceDefTarget serviceDef = (ServiceDefTarget) service;
                System.err.println(".........." + GWT.getModuleBaseURL());
                serviceDef
                        .setServiceEntryPoint("/services/registrationService");

                if (teamName.getText() == null
                        || teamName.getText().length() == 0) {
                    isValid = false;
                    statusText.append("Please specify team name. ");
                }
                Player captain = getCaptain();
                if (!atleast6PlayersAreSpecified()) {
                    isValid = false;
                    statusText.append("Please specify atleast 6 players. ");
                }
                if (captain == null) {
                    isValid = false;
                    statusText.append("Please designate a captain. ");
                }
                System.out.println("Is request valid? " + isValid);
                if (isValid.equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                    System.out.println("RPC - submitTeam start ");
                    System.out.println("" + getPlayers());
                    SubmitTeamCallback callback = new SubmitTeamCallback(status);
                    service.submitTeam(teamName.getText(), getPlayers(),
                            callback);
                    System.out.println("RPC - submitTeam end");

                } else {
                    status.setText(statusText.toString());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Made some progress after adding Window.alert(...) based on @Pistol suggestion and it is going to **onFailure(Throwable t)** method of the **SubmitTeamCallback** class.

**unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_SerializationException_SerializationException__Ljava_lang_String_2V(Unknown Source)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method to debug client side code is using [Window.alert(...)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#alert%28java.lang.String%29). For example placing it in your callback onFailure() method to see caught messages for a start. Or you can use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or something similar to see if the rpc-call is actually being made?

**Edit :**

Are you sure your Player class implements [IsSerializable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) and have an empty constructor? Check out [Serializable User-Defined Classes](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes).

Comment: +1 I used FirBug's XHR console and see that nothing is being submitted. I will use Window.alert() and see

Comment: I have Player class and Captain class (that extends from Player), both implementing Serializable and IsSerializable interfaces. and List<Player> players can contain either Player or Captain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. The POJO's should have a default constructor and the one's I am using didn't have one. GWT compiler didn't complain either. Not sure why.

Comment: that sounds exactly like my answer :)

Comment: @pistolPanties yep i didn't pay attention to the empty constructor from your post. i accepted your post as the answer. tx